# Printing in Chrome changes the layout of my page

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout, printing

I am getting a layout error when printing my page in Chrome (and only Chrome). Notice, that I am already using a `@media-print`-stylesheet and the emulation in the Developer Tools works correctly.

[image: Layout issue when printing]

The markup is basically a Bootstrap Carousel. The issue is that the image+caption (i.e. item of the carousel) are positioned below where they should be. The bar on top of the image is one of two div’s (.obscure-top/.obscure-bottom) to obscure/mask parts of the image. They are in their correct position.

```
<article>
<header>…</header>
<div id="locations-carousel-wrapper" class="box">
    <div id="locations-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="obscure-top"></div>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <a class="modelLink" href="…">
                    <img src="…" alt=""/>
                    <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="obscure-bottom"></div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" … />
        <a class="right carousel-control" …/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box box-footer"></div>
```

For the `@media-print`-stylesheet the box is absolutely positioned:

```
#locations-carousel-box {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 260px;
    right: 15px;
    top: -280px;
}
```

to get it up there. Everything else is like on the “regular” page and it works in other browsers as well as the 'print emulation'. The issue is only introduced when I actually want to print the page. Any ideas what could be the cause of this? Or any way how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is gone.

Since I can’t reproduce it anymore I assume that a Chrome update fixed this issue (possibly pdfium-related).